# How to Test C# Functions interactively with F# Interactive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, f#, read-eval-print-loop, f#-interactive

I have a set of static utility methods including unit tests. But I'd like to have a more interactive way to employ a testing -> fixing -> compiling cycle (REPL) like in Lisp or Smalltalk where one can immediately execute code in interactive mode. I tried to use F# Interactive to test these methods directly from within the opened C# project in VS 2010, but I didn't get it to work.

I know that I have to load the assembly (`#r` directive), open the namespace and then can call the methods (and inspect the result). But how do I do it within “F# Interactive” in Visual Studio 2010? I know it is possible with the “Immediate” window available in debug mode, but I want to do it within F# Interactive in "design mode", when I'm writing the code.

Comment: What is not working?  It sounds like you're spelling out the correct answer in the question?

Comment: Hey Brian! - Alas, no. I guess the problem is that the #r directive cannot use to load arbitrary dlls with a full path, but only GAC's assemblies or that within the search paths. So I came to the conclusion that I'm doing something completely wrong, and there must be another way to use F# Interactive from within the opened project. I should be easier, leaner... more interactive as in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the path to your project using the `#I` directive then you may load your assembly and use it.  I wrote a simple C# console app try this and got this to work.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintMessage();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void PrintMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in F# interactive:

```
> #I "full path to debug directory";;

--> Added 'full path to debug directory' to library include path

> #r "ConsoleApplication1.exe";;

--> Referenced 'full path to debug directory\ConsoleApplication1.exe'

> open ConsoleApplication1;;
> Program.PrintMessage();;
MESSAGE!
val it : unit = ()
```

So it definitely works, you just need to compile your projects first.  Just remember to reset your session to release your assembly beforehand.

Comment: Hi Jeff! I'll check your solution asap. Finally someone had a clue... Alas nobody in the VS2010 team wanted to push REPL coding in with F#, it would have been so valuable... (+1)

Comment: Prefix the full path with @ so backslash won't be treated as an escape character, e.g. `#I @"c:\users\myself\projects\FizzBuzz\bin\x86\Debug\";;`